# Probability of ending with 2 blue balls in a row after $n$ draws

Tags: probability, probability-theory, discrete-mathematics, probability-distributions

Thank you for taking the time to read my question.

The scenario is, we're playing a game where we have in a box 9 balls: 4 red, 3 green, 2 blue.

We draw one ball at a time, and note down its color and then return it for the next draw, the game stops only when we have drawn the same color twice in a row.

- What is the probability of the game ending after $n$ draws? $P(X=n)$?
- What is the probability of the last two balls being blue?

I have tried to treat it as a geometric probability distribution, with: p: probability of having two balls in a row with the same color $P(X=n) = n-1$ fails and then a success but this ball number 2 and 3 could be the same color in this. I've tried to discuss it case by case, starting with if the first ball is Blue, Red, Green, in hopes of noticing some recursion, but no luck. Haven't had any other ideas.

Comment: 4 red, 3 green, 2 red ?

Comment: 2 blue, apologies, fixed it

Comment: The other problem here, is you haven't said what you've tried ...

Comment: Ah yes, I have tried to treat it as a geometric probability distribution, with:
p: probability of having two balls in a row with the same color
P(X=n) = n-1 fails and then a success
but this ball number 2 and 3 could be the same color in this.

I've tried to discuss it case by case, starting with if the first ball is Blue, Red, Green, in hopes of noticing some recursion, but no luck.

Haven't had any other ideas

Comment: I would suggest you to add what you tried in the body of question (not in a comment).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an idea how to solve the problem using the Markov's chain. Possibly it is not the simplest solution but it is general enough so that it can be applied to more complicated problems as well.

Let the probabilities to draw the balls be $p_1,p_2,p_3$, respectively and let the state of the sequence be characterized by the color (type) of the last ball. Then the transition matrix  and the initial state read:
$$
T=\left(\begin{array}{ccc|c}
0&  p_1& p_1&\color{grey}0\\
p_2&0&p_2&\color{grey}0\\
p_3&p_3&0&\color{grey}0\\
\hline
\color{grey}{p_1}&\color{grey}{p_2}&\color{grey}{p_3}&\color{grey}{1}
\end{array}\right)\quad\text{and}\quad 
P_1=\begin{pmatrix}
p_1\\
p_2\\
p_3\\
\color{grey}0\\
\end{pmatrix},\tag1
$$
respectively, and  the state of the sequence after $n$ draws is
$$
P_n=T^{n-1}P_1.\tag2
$$

To make the things simpler one can note that there is no back coupling from the final state, so that it can be omitted and only the action of the "active" $3\times3$ block of the matrix onto the $3\times1$ vector of "active" states [highlighted in $(1)$] be considered. In what follows these reduced versions of the transition matrix and the state vector are assumed.

The characteristic polynomial of the active block is:
$$
Q(x)=x^3-(p_1p_2+p_2p_3+p_3p_1)x-2p_1p_2p_3,\tag3
$$
so that the probability vector $P_{n}$ can be computed by the recurrence relation:
$$
P_{n}=(p_1p_2+p_2p_3+p_3p_1)P_{n-2}+2p_1p_2p_3P_{n-3}\tag4
$$
with the elements of the three initial state vectors being:
$$
P_{0,i}=\tfrac12,\quad P_{1,i}=p_i,\quad P_{2,i}=(1-p_i)p_i.\tag5
$$
Finally the probability of ending with two balls of $i$-th color after $n$-th draw is:
$$
P_{n-1,i}\cdot p_i.\tag6
$$

Comment: I love this answer, thank you so much, wish I can upvote it publicly

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit on how we went from (3) to (4)?

Comment: If the characteristic polynomial of the transition matrix is $\sum_{k=0}^ma_k x^k$ the corresponding recurrence relation for the probabilities is $\sum_{k=0}^ma_k P_{n-m+k}=0$. This boils down to the fact that a matrix satisfies its own characteristic equation.

Comment: You are welcome. Thank you for the interesting question.

Comment: I was taking another look at this again, I had more questions, this doesn't take into consideration that the game can end prematurely no? 

if we plug in n=3, and decide to calculate the probability to end up with a blue, wouldn't we be also factoring in the probability of RBB for example? @user

Comment: @Kuro Of course it does take into account that the game can end before. You can easily check that the sum of $P_{i,n}$ is a decreasing function of $n$. The value $1-\sum_i P_{i,n}$ is exactly the probability that the game came to the end at the $n$-th draw or before.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand exactly, we took into account either the game ends at n-th draw or the draw just before it, since we made the probability of transitioning from Blue to Blue for example as 0, we're sure not to have any consecutive balls of the same color (state) in the middle of drawing? Thank you for taking the time to explain to me

Comment: Maybe I should not have omitted some details (though I mentioned this in my answer). The complete transition matrix includes of course the final state as well: $$
T=\begin{pmatrix}
0&  p_1& p_1&0\\
p_2&0&p_2&0\\
p_3&p_3&0&0\\
p_1&p_2&p_3&1
\end{pmatrix}\quad\text{with}\quad 
V_1=\begin{pmatrix}
p_1\\
p_2\\
p_3\\
0
\end{pmatrix}.
$$ The last line computes the probability of the end of the game. You can see that in this complete matrix all columns sum to $1$ as they should. The final state however does not affect anything in my answer and therefore was omitted.

Comment: ah yes I understand now, thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can treat the process as a $6$-state Markov chain.  If $\ B_t\ $ is the colour of the ball drawn at time $\ t\ $, the states are
\begin{align}
\text{State $1$:}\ &B_t=\text{red}\ \ \text{ and either }\ \ t=0\ \ \text{ or }\ \ B_{t-1}\ne\text{red}\\
\text{State $2$:}\ &B_t=\text{green}\ \ \text{ and either }\ \ t=0\ \ \text{ or }\ \ B_{t-1}\ne\text{green}\\
\text{State $3$:}\ &B_t=\text{blue}\ \ \text{ and either }\ \ t=0\ \ \text{ or }\ \ B_{t-1}\ne\text{blue}\\
\text{State $4$:}\ &B_t=B_{t-1}=\text{red}\\
\text{State $5$:}\ &B_t=B_{t-1}=\text{green}\\
\text{State $6$:}\ &B_t=B_{t-1}=\text{blue}\\
\end{align}
States $4$, $5$ and $6$ are absorbing states—where the game ends—, the transition matrix is
$$
P=\pmatrix{0&\frac{1}{3}&\frac{2}{9}&\frac{4}{9}&0&0\\
          \frac{4}{9}&0&\frac{2}{9}&0&\frac{1}{3}&0\\
        \frac{4}{9}&\frac{1}{3}&0&0&0&\frac{2}{9}\\
    0&0&0&1&0&0\\
    0&0&0&0&1&0\\
    0&0&0&0&0&1}\ ,
$$
and the initial state probabilities are
$$
\pi_0=\pmatrix{\frac{4}{9}&\frac{1}{3}&\frac{2}{9}&0&0&0}\ .
$$
The state probabilities $\ \pi_n\ $ after the $\ (n+1)^\text{th}\ $ draw are given by
$$
\pi_n=\pi_0P^n\ ,
$$
and the probability that the game ends on or before the $\ (n+1)^\text{th}\ $ draw (for $\ n\ge1\ $) is
$$
\pi_{n4}+\pi_{n5}+\pi_{n6}\ .
$$
The probability $\ f_n\ $ that it ends precisely on the $\ (n+1)^\text{th}\ $ draw is therefore given by
$$
f_n=\pi_{n4}+\pi_{n5}+\pi_{n6}-\left(\pi_{n-1\,4}+\pi_{n-1\,5}+\pi_{n-1\,6}\right)\ .
$$
[Magma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magma_(computer_algebra_system)) gives $$\ x^4-x^3-\frac{26}{81}x^2+\frac{62}{243}x+\frac{16}{243}=
(x-1)\left(x^3-\frac{26}{81}x-\frac{16}{243}\right)
$$
as the minimal polynomial of $\ P\ $. This means that $\ f_n\ $ will satisfy the recursion
$$
f_{n+4}=f_{n+3}+\frac{26}{81}f_{n+2}-\frac{62}{243}f_{n+1}-\frac{16}{243}f_n\ ,
$$
so another way of calculating $\ f_n\ $ is to use the equation
$$
\pmatrix{f_{n+1}\\f_n\\f_{n-1}\\f_{n-2}}=\pmatrix{0&1&0&0\\
             0&0&1&0\\
             0&0&0&1\\
             1&\frac{26}{81}&-\frac{62}{243}&-\frac{16}{243}}^n\pmatrix{f_n\\f_{n-1}\\f_{n-2}\\f_{n-3}}\ ,
$$
with initial condition
$$
\pmatrix{f_1\\f_2\\f_3\\f_4}=\pmatrix{\frac{29}{81}\\
\frac{2}{9}\\
\frac{970}{6561}\\
\frac{1868}{19683}}\ .
$$
An alternative is to express $\ f_n\ $ as a linear combination of powers of the roots $\ 1,\lambda_1, \lambda_2, \lambda_3\ $ of the minimal polynomial:
$$
f_n=A+B\lambda_1^n+C\lambda_2^n+D\lambda_3^n\ .
$$
Magma gives $\ 0.64985, -0.39017$ and $\ -0.25969\ $ as the approximate values of $\ \lambda_1, \lambda_2$ and $\ \lambda_3\ $ rounded to $5$ decimal places.  Since the absolute values of these are all strictly less than one, then $\ \lim_\limits{n\rightarrow\infty}f_n=A\ $, and since we know this limit must be $0$, then we have $\ A=0\ $. But, in any case, we can determine the values of $\ A,B,C$, and $\ D\ $, from the initial conditions:
$$
\pmatrix{1&\lambda_1^2&\lambda_2^2&\lambda_3^2\\
         1&\lambda_1^3&\lambda_2^3&\lambda_3^3\\
         1&\lambda_1^4&\lambda_2^4&\lambda_3^4\\
         1&\lambda_1^5&\lambda_2^5&\lambda_3^5}\pmatrix{A\\B\\C\\D}=\pmatrix{\frac{29}{81}\\
\frac{2}{9}\\
\frac{970}{6561}\\
\frac{1868}{19683}}\ . 
$$
Magma's approximate solution to these equations rounded to $5$ decimal places is $\ A=0, B=0.82440, C=0.03486\ $, and $\ D=0.08024\ $.

You can find the probability of the last two balls being blue (i.e. that the final state is state $6$) by solving a set of linear equations for the *conditional* probabilities $\ s_i\ $ that the final state is state $6$ *given* that the initial state is state $\ i\ $ for $\ i=1,2,3\ $ and then computing $\ \frac{4s_1}{9}+\frac{s_2}{3}+\frac{2s_3}{9}\ $. The equations for $\ s_i\ $ are
\begin{align}
s_1&=\frac{s_2}{3}+\frac{2s_3}{9}\\
s_2&=\frac{4s_3}{9}+\frac{2s_3}{9}\\
s_3&=\frac{4s_3}{9}+\frac{s_2}{3}+\frac{2}{9}\ ,
\end{align}
which have solution $\ s_1=\frac{16}{149}, s_2=\frac{52}{447},s_3=\frac{46}{149}\ $, so the probability that the last two balls are blue is
$$
\left(\frac{4}{9}\right)\left(\frac{16}{149}\right)+\left(\frac{1}{3}\right)\left(\frac{52}{447}\right)+\left(\frac{2}{9}\right)\left(\frac{46}{149}\right)=\frac{208}{1341}\ .
$$